# XML file to HTML Table JQuery/AJAX (Bootstrap)

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

i have been given a task to do yet i have no clue how to...i was recently handed a template that you can buy from wrapbootstrap and have been asked to populate data from an xml file into the table in the HTML. i have been researching/googling for days and still can't figure it out..

JQUERY/AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/test/testxml.xml",
      dataType: "xml",
      success: function (xml) {
          $(xml).find("datadump").each(function () {

              var User = $(this).find("User").text();
              var Value_1 = $(this).find("Value_1").text();
              var Value_2 = $(this).find("Value_2").text();
              var Value_3(this).find("Value_3").text();
          $('<tr></tr>').html('<td>'+Value_1+'</td><td>'+Value_2+'</td><td>'+Value_3+'</td>').appendTo('#data1');
          });
      }
  });
```

}

HTML CODE (Template WRAPBOOTSTRAP)

```
</div>
        <div class="row">
            <!-- begin panel -->
            <div class="col-md-7">
                <div class="panel panel-inverse">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">Performance</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                        <table id="data1 "class="table table-condensed table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>User</th>
                                    <th>Value 1</th>
                                    <th>Value 2</th>
                                    <th>Value 3</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                    <td>Value</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

XML FILE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<datadump>
<Info User="Bob" Value_1="23" Value_2="122" Value_3="45"/>
<Info User="Michael" Value_1="223" Value_2="162" Value_3="64"/>
<Info User="William" Value_1="23" Value_2="1" Value_3="45"/>
<Info User="Jeff" Value_1="23" Value_2="23" Value_3="45"/>
</datadump>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks

Comment: i have managed to populate the data as per the Jquery however am i doing it in the best method? i had to remove the td tags and they are produced via tha Jquery...any comments would be apprieciated..i would prefer that the td tags to stay with an id and i link to the xml..if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

You have to get data and parse xml in success function of ajax call
In this function you can put values in your table structure as you fetch data from xml.

See the example below :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "sites.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(xml) {
            $(xml).find('site').each(function() {
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                $(' ').html('' + title + '').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                $(this).find('desc').each(function() {
                    var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                    var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                    $(' ').html(brief).appendTo('#link_' + id);
                    $(' ').html(long).appendTo('#link_' + id);
                });
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: don't really understand the example... do you have the html and xml so i can understand the whole process? many thanks